# Is the Airbnb booking valid as proof of stay?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, italy, airbnb

I'll be traveling to Italy with my family next year for 15 days (We're Brazilians) and we will be staying on apartments rented with Airbnb. I heard immigration will ask for proof that I'm staying in a Hotel or an invitation letter.

Is the Airbnb booking valid as proof of stay?

[**EDIT**] My question differs from [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112217/germany-schengen-visa-with-airbnb-booking) because I'll be staying only 15 days.

Comment: I believe the rule is the same for all Europe Union, I have been in Portugal and I have used a Airbnb reservation to proof. 
Also, I am Brazilian.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88082/airbnb-and-justify-of-expenses